# How to enable S3 Request metrics using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I need to enable Request metrics for **AllRequests** to S3 buckets using boto3. Please help me with some hints on this.

Comment: Looks like you would use [`put_bucket_metrics_configuration()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_metrics_configuration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the [put_bucket_metrics_configuration](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_metrics_configuration) on the S3 client of boto3.

```
response = client.put_bucket_metrics_configuration(
    Bucket='my-bucket',
    Id='metrics-config-id',
    MetricsConfiguration={
        'Id': 'metrics-config-id',
        'Filter': {
            'Prefix': 'my-prefix',
        }
    }
)
```

The `Filter` property can be excluded if you just want to enable metrics for everything in the bucket.  See the documentation, it also allows you to filter based on Tags and add multiple conditions.